# TSQL Change String to DATETIME datatype - SQLSERVER 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to convert this NVARCHAR "datetime" ("28/08/2014 08:45:50") to a proper DATETIME datatype (2014-08-28 08:45:50)?

or perhaps even the other away around

> 2014-08-28 08:45:50 to "28/08/2014 08:45:50"

I've tried to CAST or CONVERT to DATETIME but I get this error

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your date format is mdy. You can changed this by setting the `DATEFORMAT` to `dmy`. For example, try this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SELECT CAST('28/08/2014 08:45:50' AS DATETIME)
```